# object:removed Event Not Fired - Fabric JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I am facing a weird issue with fabric events. Take a look at this snippet

```
canvas.on('object:added', function(e) { 
        console.log(e.target.type);
        console.log("Something was Added");

    });

 canvas.on('object:removed', function(e) { 
            console.log(e.target.type);
            console.log("Something was removed");

        });
```

Given this code base I am experimenting on an undo / redo functionality. Given both undo & redo can add , modify or remove an object I would like to be notified if something was added or removed in the canvas (I am not much worried about object modified at this stage).

But strange enough no matter if an object is added or removed from the canvas using the undo / redo functionality. **I always get the output -  Something was Added**

Undo / Redo Routines:

```
// Undo Redo Clear
        canvas.counter = 0;
        var newleft = 0;
        canvas.selection = false;
        var state = [];
        var mods = 0;
        canvas.on(
            'object:modified', function () {
                updateModifications(true);
            },
            'object:added', function () {
                updateModifications(true);
            },
            'object:removed' , function(e){
                updateModifications(true);
                console.log('test me');
            });

        function updateModifications(savehistory) {
            if (savehistory === true) {
                myjson = JSON.stringify(canvas);
                state.push(myjson);
                console.log(myjson);
            }
        }

        undo = function undo() {
            if (mods < state.length) {
                canvas.clear().renderAll();
                canvas.loadFromJSON(state[state.length - 1 - mods - 1]);
                canvas.renderAll();

                mods += 1;
                //check_team();

                //compare_states(state[state.length - 1 - mods - 1] , state[state.length - 1 - mods + 1])

            }
            //make_objects_selectable();
        }

        redo = function redo() {
            if (mods > 0) {
                canvas.clear().renderAll();
                canvas.loadFromJSON(state[state.length - 1 - mods + 1]);
                canvas.renderAll();

                mods -= 1;

                //check_team(); 
            }
            //make_objects_selectable();
        }

        clearcan = function clearcan() {
            canvas.clear().renderAll();
            newleft = 0;
        }
```

Fabric version:"1.6.0-rc.1"

Update: The Event is working fine in case of a normal delete action. Hence I added the Undo and Redo Routines.

Regards

Answer (score 3):

Both your undo and redo functions do basically the same thing, erase canvas, load a new state and render it. When you clear the canvas, there is no `object:removed` event, but another event is fired, called `canvas:cleared`. That is why you never see your `object:removed` event fired when doing undo/redo. On the other hand, you do see `object:added` fired on both undo and redo, because I am guessing that `canvas.renderAll` adds every object on the current state into the canvas (since it was previously removed with canvas.clear()).

**EDIT**

A better solution is to store every action that happens on canvas, like add, modify or remove, and have each action associated with some object data. For example, you could have an `object_added` action associated with a serialization of the added object, or an `object_removed` action associated with a serialization of the removed object. For `object_modified` you would need two associated object serializations, one prior modification and one after modification. In case of a `canvas_cleared` action, you would have to store the whole canvas state as associative data.

A simple stack structure can work great for the purpose of action storage.

```js
function SimpleStackException(msg) {
  this.message = msg;
  this.name = 'SimpleStackException';
}

function SimpleStack() {
  var MAX_ENTRIES = 2048;
  var self = this;
  self.sp = -1; // stack pointer
  self.entries = []; // stack heap

  self.push = function(newEntry) {
    if (self.sp > MAX_ENTRIES - 1) {
      throw new SimpleStackException('Can not push on a full stack.');
    }
    self.sp++;
    self.entries[self.sp] = newEntry;
    // make sure to clear the "future" stack after a push occurs
    self.entries.splice(self.sp + 1, self.entries.length);
  };

  self.pop = function() {
    if (self.sp < 0) {
      throw new SimpleStackException('Can not pop from an empty stack.');
    }
    var entry = self.entries[self.sp];
    self.sp--;
    return entry;
  };

  self.reversePop = function() {
    self.sp++;
    if (!self.entries[self.sp]) {
      self.sp--;
      throw new SimpleStackException('Can not reverse pop an entry that has never been created.');
    }
    return self.entries[self.sp];
  }

}
```

Go ahead and create such a structure: 
`var actionHistory = new SimpleStack();`

Another feature you will need for the action-based undo/redo to work, is the ability to "reference" objects in the canvas. In fabric.js you can reference objects from `canvas.getObjects()`, but that is a plain js array and does not help much. I have added object IDs, in the form of UUID.
Here is a function (taken somewhere in SO, dont have the link now) tha generates UUIDs

```js
var lut = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
  lut[i] = (i < 16 ? '0' : '') + (i).toString(16);
}

function generateUuid() {
  var d0 = Math.random() * 0xffffffff | 0;
  var d1 = Math.random() * 0xffffffff | 0;
  var d2 = Math.random() * 0xffffffff | 0;
  var d3 = Math.random() * 0xffffffff | 0;
  return lut[d0 & 0xff] + lut[d0 >> 8 & 0xff] + lut[d0 >> 16 & 0xff] + lut[d0 >> 24 & 0xff] + '-' +
    lut[d1 & 0xff] + lut[d1 >> 8 & 0xff] + '-' + lut[d1 >> 16 & 0x0f | 0x40] + lut[d1 >> 24 & 0xff] + '-' +
    lut[d2 & 0x3f | 0x80] + lut[d2 >> 8 & 0xff] + '-' + lut[d2 >> 16 & 0xff] + lut[d2 >> 24 & 0xff] +
    lut[d3 & 0xff] + lut[d3 >> 8 & 0xff] + lut[d3 >> 16 & 0xff] + lut[d3 >> 24 & 0xff];
}
```

In order for fabric objects to have a new uuid property you need to add it to the object prototype, and to the object serialization method as well

```js
fabric.Object.prototype.uuid = "";
fabric.Object.prototype.toObject = (function(toObject) {
  return function() {
    return fabric.util.object.extend(toObject.call(this), {
      uuid: this.uuid,
    });
  };
})(fabric.Object.prototype.toObject);
```

Finally you need a function to "reference" objects via this uuid property.

```js
function getFabricObjectByUuid(uuid) {
  var fabricObject = null;
  canvas.getObjects().forEach(function(object) {
    if (object.uuid === uuid) {
      fabricObject = object;
    }
  });
  return fabricObject;
}
```

Now you need to listen for events on the canvas, and update the `actionHistory` accordingly:

```js
canvas.on('path:created', function(path) {
  var object = path.path;
  object.uuid = generateUuid();
  actionHistory.push({
    type: 'object_added',
    object: JSON.stringify(object)
  });
});
canvas.on('object:added', function(e) {
  var object = e.target;
  // bypass the event for path objects, as they are handled by `path:created`
  if (object.type === 'path') {
    return;
  }
  // if the object has not been given an uuid, that means it is a fresh object created by this client
  if (!object.uuid) {
    object.uuid = generateUuid();
  }
  if (!object.bypassHistory) {
    actionHistory.push({
      type: 'object_added',
      object: JSON.stringify(object)
    });
  }
});
canvas.on('object:modified', function(e) {
  var object = e.target;
  actionHistory.push({
    type: 'object_modified',
    objectOld: JSON.stringify(latestTouchedObject),
    objectNew: JSON.stringify(object)
  });
});
canvas.on('text:changed', function(e) {
  var object = e.target;
  actionHistory.push({
    type: 'text_changed',
    objectOld: JSON.stringify(latestTouchedObject),
    objectNew: JSON.stringify(object)
  });
});
canvas.on('object:removed', function(e) {
  var object = e.target;
  if (!object.bypassHistory) {
    actionHistory.push({
      type: 'object_removed',
      object: JSON.stringify(object)
    });
  }
});
canvas.on('canvas:cleared', function(e) {
  if (!canvas.bypassHistory) {
    actionHistory.push({
      type: 'canvas_cleared',
      canvas: JSON.stringify(canvas)
    });
  }
});
```

Check out each event handler carefully to understand the actual data that will be stored on `actionHistory`. Also be mindful when the `uuid` property is actually added to an object. There are two things to note about the above snippet.

1. bypassHistory is a custom property of canvas objects and the canvas itself. You only want to store actions that are willingly performed by a user onto the canvas. If a user hand-draws a line, you want to save that action, and you do so by listening to `path:cleared`. However, in the case  of a programmatically drawn line (eg. when performing a redo), you may not want to store the action. To add this custom property do as follows:

   fabric.Object.prototype.bypassHistory = false; // default value false
2. object_modified is a special action because it needs to store two object representations: before and after modification. While the "after" version is obtained easily via `event.target` of the `object:modified` event, the "before" version has to be tracked programmatically. In my solution i have a high level `latestTouchedObject` variable that keeps track of the latest modified object on the canvas.

```js
canvas.on('mouse:down', function(options) {
  if (options.target) {
    latestTouchedObject = fabric.util.object.clone(options.target);
  }
});
```

Now that the action storage and all listeners have been setup, it's time to implement the undo and redo functions

```js
function undoAction() {
  var action, objectCandidate;
  try {
    action = actionHistory.pop();
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e.message);
    return;
  }
  if (action.type === 'object_added') {
    objectCandidate = JSON.parse(action.object);
    var object = getFabricObjectByUuid(objectCandidate.uuid);
    object.bypassHistory = true;
    canvas.remove(object);
  } else if (action.type === 'object_removed') {
    objectCandidate = JSON.parse(action.object);
    fabric.util.enlivenObjects([objectCandidate], function(actualObjects) {
      actualObjects[0].uuid = objectCandidate.uuid;
      var object = actualObjects[0];
      object.bypassHistory = true;
      canvas.add(object);
      object.bypassHistory = false;
    });
  } else if (action.type === 'object_modified' || action.type === 'text_changed') {
    objectCandidate = JSON.parse(action.objectOld);
    fabric.util.enlivenObjects([objectCandidate], function(actualObjects) {
      actualObjects[0].uuid = objectCandidate.uuid;
      var object = actualObjects[0];
      var existingObject = getFabricObjectByUuid(objectCandidate.uuid);
      if (existingObject) {
        existingObject.bypassRemoveEvent = true;
        existingObject.bypassHistory = true;
        canvas.remove(existingObject);
      }
      object.bypassHistory = true;
      canvas.add(object);
      object.bypassHistory = false;
    });
  } else if (action.type === 'canvas_cleared') {
    var canvasPresentation = JSON.parse(action.canvas);
    canvas.bypassHistory = true;
    canvas.loadFromJSON(canvasPresentation);
    canvas.renderAll();
    canvas.bypassHistory = false;
  }
}

function redoAction() {
  var action, objectCandidate;
  try {
    action = actionHistory.reversePop();
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e.message);
    return;
  }
  if (action.type === 'object_added') {
    objectCandidate = JSON.parse(action.object);
    fabric.util.enlivenObjects([objectCandidate], function(actualObjects) {
      actualObjects[0].uuid = objectCandidate.uuid;
      var object = actualObjects[0];
      object.bypassHistory = true;
      canvas.add(object);
      object.bypassHistory = false;
    });
  } else if (action.type === 'object_removed') {
    objectCandidate = JSON.parse(action.object);
    var object = getFabricObjectByUuid(objectCandidate.uuid);
    object.bypassHistory = true;
    canvas.remove(object);
    object.bypassHistory = false;
  } else if (action.type === 'object_modified' || action.type === 'text_changed') {
    objectCandidate = JSON.parse(action.objectNew);
    fabric.util.enlivenObjects([objectCandidate], function(actualObjects) {
      actualObjects[0].uuid = objectCandidate.uuid;
      var object = actualObjects[0];
      var existingObject = getFabricObjectByUuid(objectCandidate.uuid);
      if (existingObject) {
        existingObject.bypassRemoveEvent = true;
        existingObject.bypassHistory = true;
        canvas.remove(existingObject);
      }
      object.bypassHistory = true;
      canvas.add(object);
      object.bypassHistory = false;
    });
  } else if (action.type === 'canvas_cleared') {
    canvas.clear();
  }
}
```

I dont know if this solution (and code) fits your needs out-of-the-box. Maybe it is at some degree coupled to my specific application. I hope you manage to understand what i propose and make use of it.

Comment: Yup, it seems to be the case. What do you suggest to overcome the problem in hand. I must know if an object is removed from the current state. I was thinking I compare both the json object somehow and find out what's missing. But that by the thought of it sounds tedious.

Comment: I dont think you can achieve that with your approach. You just store a plain serialization of the whole canvas on each "state slot", and that serialization is difficult to query for individual objects. I will give you an updated answer (later today) with my solution, which is based on a Stack with individual objects and actions, rather than whole canvas storage.

Comment: That would be very helpful

Comment: Thats a good approach. But how do you suggest we can be sure when to pop or push something? If the events are not at our disposal?

Comment: Check out my kind of messy solution.